# How to force the query optimiser to handle my query more efficiently?

Tags: sql-server

I have a report scheduling system where each report has a set of parameters that the user is prompted for dynamically and then the report executes as a SQL Agent job saving the output to an archive database for review later.

This all worked fine but users wanted to change one of the parameters.  They used to specify a single Member and Location (this defines a customer) but now they want to be able to specify multiple Member and Locations.  For example, they might want to see the Top 50 products by sales for Comet in 2012 based on their operations in the UK and NI (two locations).

My report used to take seconds to run, but with this change it now takes around 8 minutes!

When the report scheduler picks up the request for a report it stores the list of Member/ Locations in a table and this is then linked into the report.  This seems to be where things are going wrong.

Here is the start of the report (this is enough to get the performance issue):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Report].[GetTopSaleQuantityPackagingTonnage] (
    @ReportHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @DSFYear INT,
    @DateFrom DATETIME,
    @DateTo DATETIME,   
    @LevelId INT,
    @MaterialId INT, --Base Material
    @TopN INT,
    @TopNType VARCHAR(50),
    @WeightSource VARCHAR(50),
    @ImportExportFlag VARCHAR(1) = NULL)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    WITH MemberList AS (
        SELECT 
            MemberId, 
            LocationId 
        FROM 
            Report.ReportMemberLocation 
        WHERE 
            ReportHandle = @ReportHandle),
    ProductList AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            pw.ProductId,
            pw.WeightSource,
            m.MaterialId
        FROM
            PackagingWeightDerivedBase pw
            INNER JOIN Material m ON m.ExtendedMaterialId = pw.ExtendedMaterialId
        WHERE
            EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MemberList ml WHERE ml.MemberId = pw.MemberId)
            AND ISNULL(@LevelId, pw.LevelId) = pw.LevelId
            AND ISNULL(@MaterialId, m.MaterialId) = m.MaterialId)
SELECT * FROM ProductList;
```

If I add a single filter to the ProductList CTE, e.g.

```
AND MemberId = 163
```

then it goes back to taking seconds rather than minutes.  MemberId = 163 is the member I am running the report for and, in this case, they only have a single location anyway.

I originally tried this:

```
    ProductList AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            pw.ProductId,
            pw.WeightSource,
            m.MaterialId
        FROM
            MemberList ml
            INNER JOIN PackagingWeightDerivedBase pw ON pw.MemberId = ml.MemberId
            INNER JOIN Material m ON m.ExtendedMaterialId = pw.ExtendedMaterialId
        WHERE
            ISNULL(@LevelId, pw.LevelId) = pw.LevelId
            AND ISNULL(@MaterialId, m.MaterialId) = m.MaterialId)
```

...but that was even slower, I left it for 30 minutes and it never completed.  Also, this is not strictly correct in any case as it would bring back duplicate results for every row in the Member/ Location filter.

So I know the problem is that the optimiser is not handling this sensibly.  Basically it has:

```
Report.ReportMemberLocation - 1 row
Material - about 50 rows
PackagingWeightDerivedBase - millions of rows
```

...and it must be pulling out millions of rows of data just to throw 99.99% of them away when it spots that they belong to different members.

Is there any other way I can express this query to force the optimiser to filter the Weight table by the Member list first?  Or maybe some hint I am missing?

Comment: You can put a `with (index=INDEX_NAME)` after one of the tables to coerce it to use that index

Comment: The problem with that is that the PackagingWeightDerivedBase is actually a view and that is where I would need to add an index hint

Comment: After spending literally all day messing around with this I decided the only sensible way forward was to add a rule that only one member at a time may be included.  This works reasonably well as I can then use the member directly in the WHERE clause, performance goes back to being okay and users are happy as they still get to run reports across multiple locations in one hit.